# Existence of unitary matrix that produces quantum coin with given frequencies via iteration

Tags: quantum-gate

I'm curious about for which $n$ there exists a $2\times 2$ unitary matrix $U(n)$ such that for $1 \le k \le n$ $$|U^k_{1,0}(n)|^2 = \frac kn,$$
where $U^k_{1,0}(n)$ is the lower left element of the $k$th power of $U(n)$.

The idea is that if such a matrix exists, then applying it $k$ times to the quantum state $|0\rangle$ will produce the quantum state $\sqrt{1-k/n}|0\rangle + \sqrt{k/n}|1\rangle$ modulo some phases, a "quantum coin" with probability $k/n$ of giving outcome 1.

It's easy to see that it exists for $n=2$, with an example being
$$U(2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
but I couldn't find an example for any other $n$. A bit of brute force shows that no such matrices exist for $n=3$, and suggests that indeed no other $n$ works. Perhaps there's an elegant way to prove this? Or maybe there is a construction that I missed?

---

I originally posted this question on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3931577), but nobody was interested about it there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a general construction. We know that, to satisfy the $k=1$ instance, we need $U_{1,0}=1/\sqrt{n}$, up to a possible phase. But we can always take one of the elements of $U$ to be real by removing a global phase.

We also know that the sum mod-square of the rows and columns for a unitary is 1, and that the rows must be mutually orthogonal. This gives us a lot of structure for $U$.
$$
U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{n-1}e^{i\theta_1} & -e^{i(\theta_4+\theta_1)} \\
1 & \sqrt{n-1}e^{i\theta_4} \end{array}\right).
$$
Now we just start multiplying it together. We find that
$$
|U_{1,0}^2(n)|^2=\frac{4(n-1)}{n^2}\cos^2((\theta_1-\theta_4)/2).
$$
So, for all $n\geq 2$, there's a solution for $\theta_1-\theta_4$ that gives a working $k=2$. Next, $k=3$:
$$
|U_{1,0}^3(n)|^2=\frac{(2 (n-1) \cos (\theta_1-\theta_4)+n-2)^2}{n^3}
$$
Since we already know the value of $\cos^2((\theta_1-\theta_4)/2)=n/(2(n-1))$, we can use the double angle formula to find $\cos (\theta_1-\theta_4)=1/(n-1)$. Hence
$$
|U_{1,0}^3(n)|^2=\frac{1}{n}\neq\frac{3}{n}.
$$
Hence, this *only* works for $n=1,2$ where we do not require that the $k=3$ condition is satisfied.

---

For a more elegant version, note that if the relation holds for $k=n$, it must be that
$$
U^n=e^{i\phi}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & e^{-i\theta} \\ e^{i\theta} & 0 \end{array}\right)=e^{i\phi}(\cos\theta X+\sin\theta Y).
$$
$U$ must be an $n^{th}$ root of this, so
$$
U^k=e^{ik\phi/n}\left(I\cos(k\pi/(2n))+i\sin(k\pi/(2n))(\cos\theta X+\sin\theta Y)\right).
$$
In other words,
$$
|U^k_{1,0}|^2=\sin^2(k\pi/(2n))\neq \frac{k}{n},
$$
with the exception of $k=1,n=2$ which, as we already know, *does* work.
(There are a few phase freedoms floating around here, but they don't make a difference to the final answer. I don't want to worry about them because it detracts from the simple concept of this answer.)

Comment: Your "more elegant" version is not correct. It excludes the case $k=1,n=2$, for which the construction does work. A possible solution for $|U^k_{1,0}|^2$ is $\sin^2(k\pi/(2n))$, but this is not the most general possible, as for $k=1,n=3$ it does not allow for $X^3 = X$.

Comment: @MateusAraújo I was being lazy about the one case that we do know does work. As for your second comment, this was what I meant by "there are a few phase freedoms" One of those is that the rotation angle of $U$ can be any $\alpha$ such that $n\alpha\text{ mod }2\pi=\pi$.

Comment: But it seems I did miss a factor of 1/2 in the angle of rotation.

Comment: But the missing phases do matter. In general you have $|U^k_{1,0}|^2 = \sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{n}(\frac12 + l))$ for any integer $l$.

Comment: I agree they give different numbers. I don't believe they give a different conclusion.

Comment: They won't give a different conclusion because we have the proof of impossibility above. But what you have below is not a proof, from that alone you cannot conclude anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct version of the "elegant" version of DaftWullie's answer.

If the relation holds for $k=n$, then
$$ U^n = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & e^{-i\theta} \\ e^{i\theta} & 0 \end{pmatrix}, $$ modulo a global phase. Since the eigenvalues of $U^n$ are $\pm 1$, we have that $(I+U)/2$ and $(I-U)/2$ are orthogonal projectors, and thus
$$ U = e^{i \frac{2\pi a}{n}}(I+U^n)/2 + e^{i(\frac\pi n+\frac{2\pi b}{n})}(I-U^n)/2$$
for some integers $a,b$. The $k$th power is then just
$$ U^k = e^{i \frac{2\pi k a}{n}}(I+U^n)/2 + e^{i(\frac{\pi k} n+\frac{2\pi k b}{n})}(I-U^n)/2$$
Modulo a global phase, $U^k$ is then equal to
$$ {U'}^k = I(1+e^{i(\frac{\pi k} n+\frac{2\pi k l}{n})})/2 + U^n(1-e^{i(\frac{\pi k} n+\frac{2\pi k l}{n})})/2,$$
for some integer $l$, which implies that
$$|U^k_{1,0}|^2 = \sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\left(\frac12+l\right)\right).$$ This will be equal to $k/n$ for $l=0$ and $n=2k$, for example. In general it doesn't work, though, because for $k=1$ we need that
$$\frac{\pi}{n}\left(\frac12+l\right) = \pm\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, $$
but $\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is only a rational multiple of $\pi$ for $n=1,2,$ and $4$.

The cases $n=1,2$ do work, but for $n=4$ we would need
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac12+l\right) = \pm\frac{\pi}{6}, $$
which is not possible for integer $l$.